# how to ingest a table specification file in .txt form and create a table in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, etl

I tried a few different ways, below but having trouble a) removing the width and b) removing the \n with a comma. I have a txt file like the below and I want to take that information and create a table in sqlite (all using python)

```
"field",width, type
name, 15, string
revenue, 10, decimal
invoice_date, 10, string
amount, 2, integer
```

Current python code - trying to read in the file, and get the values to pass in the sql statement below

import os
import pandas as pd

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

file = open(str(dir_path) + '/revenue/revenue_table_specifications.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()
table = lines[2::]

s = ''.join(str(table).split(','))
x = s.replace("\n", ",").strip()
print(x)
```

sql I want to pass in

```
c = sqlite3.connect('rev.db') #connnect to DB
try: 
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE
                    revenue_table (information from txt file,
                             information from txt file,
                             ....)''')
except sqlite3.OperationalError: #i.e. table exists already
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces something that will work.

```
def makesql(filename):
    s = []
    for row in open(filename):
        if row[0] == '"':
            continue
        parts = row.strip().split(", ")
        s.append( f"{parts[0]} {parts[2]}" )
    return "CREATE TABLE revenue_table (\n" + ",\n".join(s) + ");"

sql = makesql( 'x.csv' )
print(sql)
c.execute( sql )
```

Comment: thank you but file comes in as .txt, not csv

Comment: How does that matter in the slightest?  Answer: it does not.  Call the file `xxx.xxx` if you want.  It's just a name.

Comment: touche thank you - I am now getting : 


    s.append( f"{parts[0]} {parts[2]}" )


As well , is this function dynamic in that if I get different specification files  with different roles will it adjust - as the hardcoded [0][2] makes me think not?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  If the name is in the first column and the type is in the third, this will work.  If you have data that doesn't match your sample, then we cannot be expected to know that.  This, at least, gives you the template.  It would be a bit harder with other databases.  Sqlite doesn't care about types at all -- everything is a string.

Comment: ok understood thank you, I had to change the [2] in the f  string to [-1].